# Windows 8, USB Ports Malfunctioning

Tags: windows-8, usb

Today I started getting the "The last USB device you connected to this computer malfunctioned, and Windows does not recognize it" message. People have reported this happening to pen drives when first plugged in, but this is different.

I was using my graphics tablet, and it had been plugged in for some time when I heard the USB disconnect, then connect noises and then the message popped up, and my tablet would no longer work. At first I thought it was something wrong with my graphics tablet, but then I discovered my mouse started acting weird too and when I reconnected it, it stopped working entirely.

When I unplug or plug things back in, there is no longer a sound or indication that the computer responded to it. It's like the USB system has shut down entirely. The light on my tablet flashes on, indicating that it has power. Restarting the computer fixes the problem, but then it happens again an hour or so later.

My computer is running Windows 8.1 64-bit and it is an HP 15-r210dx. It's brand new, I've only had it for a couple months.

Comment: Are you plugging in these devices to a USB 3.0 port? I've had 2 devices **literally** burn out after leaving them plugged in. I've had a Bluetooth dongle painfully burn my hand, after indicating power and, diagnosing why it wouldn't connect to devices. I've also had a wifi dongle (granted, a crappy knock off from china) that ended with a burned circuit board. However, you mention a restart fixes the issue? As in the USB devices work/function as normal?

Comment: It looks like it is 3.0, and yes. Restarting returns everything to normal. I've restarted for a second time and I'll have to see how long it takes for them to go out again and see if anything triggers it.

Comment: Update: It seems to happen whenever I move my tablet from my desk to my lap. This could mean there's something wrong with the USB cable, but that doesn't explain why it's shutting down all of my USB ports, unless it's causing some kind of short or something. I do transport my tablet a lot, and when I do, I wrap the cable around itself, which I admit I know is bad since it tends to cause kinks.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall your USB host controllers and then let windows re-detect everything again.

Would be worth checking for updated USB Drivers.
Also are you running directly off the ports or through a USB Hub.
Some devices using more power than what a hub can deliver causing this to happen.